# Invalid hook call. Hooks can called inside of the body of a function component / Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror

Hey i need some help guys, im pretty new to React and was trying to create a personalpage with help of a tutorial and started with the navbar, but as soon as i tried to load the page i got some error msgs.

[image: Error msg]

can someone help me understand and solve the issue, thanks

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { NavBar } from './components/NavBar';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <NavBar />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

NavBar.js:

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from '../assets/img/logo.svg';
import navIcon1 from '../assets/img/nav-icon1.svg';
import navIcon2 from '../assets/img/nav-icon2.svg';
import navIcon3 from '../assets/img/nav-icon3.svg';

export const NavBar = () => {
  const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = useState('home');
  const [scrolled, seScrolled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
      if(window.scrollY > 50) {
        seScrolled(true)
      } else {
        seScrolled(false)
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
  }, [])

  const onUpdateActiveLink = (value) => {
    setActiveLink(value);
  }

  return(
    <Navbar expand="lg" className={scrolled ? "scrolled" : ""}>
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
          <img src={logo} alt='Logo' />
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav">
          <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
        </Navbar.Toggle>
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home" className={activeLink === 'home' ? 'active navbar-link' : 'navbar-link'} onClick={() => onUpdateActiveLink('home')}>Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#skills" className={activeLink === 'skills' ? 'active navbar-link' : 'navbar-link'} onClick={() => onUpdateActiveLink('skills')}>Skills</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#projects" className={activeLink === 'projects' ? 'active navbar-link' : 'navbar-link'} onClick={() => onUpdateActiveLink('projects')}>Projects</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
          <span className='navbar-text'>
            <div className='social-icon'>
              <a href='...'>img src={navIcon1} alt=''</a>
              <a href='...'>img src={navIcon2} alt=''</a>
              <a href='...'>img src={navIcon3} alt=''</a>
            </div>
            <button className='vvd' onClick={() => console.log('connect<')}><span>Let's Connect</span></button>
          </span>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  )
}
```

I have tried multiple things but nothing worked for me...

Comment: Hi @Dreamchvser ,

I am not facing any issue might be there is some another issue in your code base. please have a look on this link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-p8rneg?file=src%2FApp.js

I have implemented the same code.

Might be somewhere you are using useRef inside useEffect then only this error will come.

Thanks

Comment: import NavBar  from './components/NavBar';  first write properly

Comment: export default NavBar;

Comment: @SourabhKumar Ty, i figured it out, something went wrong while installing the Frameworks as it seems.. i reinstalled now its working.. also i found some more mistakes i made.. 
Thanks for your help :)